# Setting Android Wallpaper with a Button with JSON looks blurry

Tags: android, json, set, resolution, wallpaper

[image: Blurry Wall]

I'm making an icon pack at the moment, and one of the sections of my app is a wallpaper chooser. The app pulls all the images through a json file described in my strings.xml, and it works fine all images render in the app, but when I choose to set the wallpaper, the wallpaper looks extremely blurry.

Below is the WallpaperFragment.java portion of code. Hopefully someone can help me find the issue :)

```
public void applyImage () {
    if (this.mImageDrawableSet == false) {
        this.mApplyImageOnDisplay = true;
        return;
    }

    try {
        final Bitmap bitmap = getImageBitmap();
        if (bitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        final WallpaperManager wpManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity());
        if (wpManager == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        wpManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wallpaper Set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public Bitmap getImageBitmap () {
    try {
        final Drawable drawable = this.mImageView.getDrawable();
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of what the JSON looks like containing the wallpaper:

```
{
  "wallpapers": {
    "category": [
    {
      "name": "SuperHeroes",
      "wallpaper": [
        {
          "author": "Simon Tucker",
          "url": "http://i.imgur.com/GD1xFTx.png",
          "thumbUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/5R1WLWB.png",
          "name": "Minimal Superman"
        }
      ]
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are getting the thumbUrl instead of url?

Comment: I just tried applying the thumbnail image and it gives a separate result. I'll add an example of the blurriness to the post in a minute

Comment: If you look you can see the pixelation in the screenshot. All the wallpapers are set to 2550x1920 resolution, so this should be perfectly sharp, but it's not